# Clojure read in file to 2D vector

Tags: file, clojure

I have a simple text file containing content like this

```
############
#P.........#
#..........#
#..........#
#..........#
#..........#
############
```

I want to be able to load this info into a 2D vector, so I can index tiles with their x/y coordinates

I've tried

```
(defn read-in-board [filepath]
  (str/split-lines (slurp filepath)))
```

Printing the result then outputs the following

```
[############ #P.........# #..........# #..........# #..........# #..........# ############]
```

I'm wondering how I could convert the characters in each String to individual vectors

i.e. Line 1

```
[[#][#][#][#][#][#][#][#][#][#][#][#].... Line 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see what's wrong with your current solution. If I have a `temp.txt` file with the contents you gave in your question, I can read it using your `read-in-board` function and access any character by its coordinates using `get-in`:

```
(let [board (read-in-board "temp.txt")]
  (str (get-in board [1 1])))
;=> "P"
```

If you really need a 2D vector of characters, though, you can get one like this:

```
(mapv vec (read-in-board "temp.txt"))
;=> [[\# \# \# \# \# \# \# \# \# \# \# \#]
;    [\# \P \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \#]
;    [\# \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \#]
;    [\# \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \#]
;    [\# \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \#]
;    [\# \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \#]
;    [\# \# \# \# \# \# \# \# \# \# \# \#]]
```

Since a string is a sequence, `vec` converts a string to a vector of characters. Therefore, you can use `mapv` to apply that function to every element of the board and get back a vector as a result.

This would allow you to use `assoc-in` and `update-in`, as Piotrek Bzdyl pointed out.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the get-in function! Thank you very much

Comment: Extra Question: Do you know if it is then possible to update values in the board?

Comment: Attempting to use (assoc-in board [0 0] "D") throws an error: java.lang.String cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Associative

Comment: @JackEvans As I said in my answer, if you want to use `assoc-in` and `update-in`, you need to convert to a 2D vector, which you can do with `mapv` and `vec`.

Comment: But assoc-in works if I map the whole thing as a vector(as Elogent's answer describes)